# Overwrite values to NaN based on conditions (different for each column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
                  A        B        C
2019-10-10  110.375  111.475  113.600
2019-10-11  111.125  112.325  114.225
2019-10-14  111.875  113.150  115.450
2019-10-15  112.175  113.500  115.600
```

For each column, I have a cutoff date (a date after which I don't need data for that column):

```
  Col      Cutoff
0   A  2019-10-10
1   B  2019-10-14
2   C  2019-10-15
```

For each column of the df, I want to change cells values to NaN if the date (the index of the df) is after the cutoff date for that column. This is the expected output:

```
                  A        B        C
2019-10-10  110.375  111.475  113.600
2019-10-11      NaN  112.325  114.225
2019-10-14      NaN  113.150  115.450
2019-10-15      NaN      NaN  115.600
```

I guess I could do this with a loop column by column, but maybe there's a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) for helper DataFrame with same columns like original, then comapre for greater by [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) and set `NaN`s by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
s = df1.set_index('Col')['Cutoff']

lens = len(df.columns)
m = pd.DataFrame(df.index.repeat(lens).to_numpy().reshape(-1, lens),
                 index=df.index, 
                 columns=df.columns).gt(s)

df = df.mask(m)
print (df)
                  A        B        C
2019-10-10  110.375  111.475  113.600
2019-10-11      NaN  112.325  114.225
2019-10-14      NaN  113.150  115.450
2019-10-15      NaN      NaN  115.600
```

Comment: Thanks. With my real dataframe the .gt function raises the following error: "Value should be a 'Timestamp', 'NaT', or array of those. Got 'FloatingArray' instead".
and "Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and ndarray"
Do you have any idea why? I checked dtypes: columns of "m" and "s" all are datetime64[ns]

Comment: @younggotti - add `df1['Cutoff'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Cutoff'])`

Comment: I had already tried that (and to be sure I did it also on the index of df) but I get the same error. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, because your solution works fine on the sample dfs

Comment: @younggotti - There is same error? Maybe need also `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

Comment: I got it: the problem is that df1 may have in the "Col" column values that are not column names of df (so for example it can have ["A", "B", "C", "D"]. I fixed that with column_list = list(df) and df1 = df1[df1['Col'].isin(column_list)]